# Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.j s'

Tags: heroku, webpack, angular-cli

I upgraded from `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.21` to `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.25.5`, making all necessary changes to get my app running with `ng serve` successfully. However, when I attempt to deploy to Heroku, it fails with the curious error below.

```
remote:        ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
remote:        Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.j  s' in '/tmp/build_7c419ad06257b748ec6f7c819360bd4b':
remote:        Error: Can't resolve 'html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js' in '/tmp/build_7c419a  d06257b748ec6f7c819360bd4b'
remote:        
remote:        - compiler.js:76
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16
remote:        
remote:        - Compiler.js:280 Compiler.<anonymous>
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:280:10
remote:        
remote:        - Compiler.js:480
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:480:13
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:138 next
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:138:11
remote:        
remote:        - CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.<anonymous>
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:142 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:142:13
remote:        
remote:        - Compiler.js:477
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:477:10
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:138 next
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:138:11
remote:        
remote:        - suppress-entry-chunks-webpack-plugin.js:38 Compilation.<anonymous>
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/plugins/suppress-entry-chunks-webpack-plugin.js:38:17
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:142 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:142:13
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:615 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:615:19
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:606 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:606:11
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:138 next
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:138:11
remote:        
remote:        - UglifyJsPlugin.js:140 Compilation.compilation.plugin
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin.js:140:5
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:142 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:142:13
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:601 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:601:10
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:597 sealPart2
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:597:9
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:545 Compilation.seal
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:545:8
remote:        
remote:        - Compiler.js:474
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:474:16
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:225
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:225:11
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:452 _addModuleChain
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:452:11
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:345 Compilation.errorAndCallback
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:345:4
remote:        
remote:        - Compilation.js:362 moduleFactory.create
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:362:12
remote:        
remote:        - NormalModuleFactory.js:234
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:234:19
remote:        
remote:        - NormalModuleFactory.js:59 onDoneResolving
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:59:20
remote:        
remote:        - NormalModuleFactory.js:126
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:126:20
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:3694
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:3694:9
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:356
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:356:16
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:934 iteratorCallback
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:934:13
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:840
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:840:16
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:3691
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:3691:13
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:21 apply
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:21:25
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:56
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:56:12
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:1013
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:1013:9
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:356
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:356:16
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:934 iteratorCallback
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:934:13
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:840
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:840:16
remote:        
remote:        - async.js:1010
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[async]/dist/async.js:1010:13
remote:        
remote:        - NormalModuleFactory.js:262
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:262:19
remote:        
remote:        - Resolver.js:70 onResolved
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:70:11
remote:        
remote:        - createInnerCallback.js:31 loggingCallbackWrapper
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/createInnerCallback.js:    31:19
remote:        
remote:        - Resolver.js:138 afterInnerCallback
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:138:10
remote:        
remote:        - createInnerCallback.js:31 loggingCallbackWrapper
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/createInnerCallback.js:    31:19
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:181 Resolver.applyPluginsAsyncSeriesBailResult1
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:181:46
remote:        
remote:        - Resolver.js:125 innerCallback
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/Resolver.js:125:19
remote:        
remote:        - createInnerCallback.js:31 loggingCallbackWrapper
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/createInnerCallback.js:    31:19
remote:        
remote:        - Tapable.js:283
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:283:15
remote:        
remote:        - UnsafeCachePlugin.js:39
remote:        [lib]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/[enhanced-resolve]/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:39    :4
remote:        
remote:
```

I know very little about the internals of Angular CLI and WebPack (and friends) so it not clear to me if this is a webpack or html-webpack-plugin issue. Any ideas???

**NOTES:**

- `package.json` syntax is valid;
- `ng serve` works on local Linux machine;
- `ng serve --prod` works on local Linux machine;
- adding `html-webpack-plugin` dependency changes nothing;
- adding `webpack` dependency changes nothing;
- project files are all UNIX encoded;
- `html-webpack-plugin@2.26.0`;
- `webpack@2.2.0`;
- `@ngtools/webpack@1.2.4`;

Comment: This occurs with a brand new project with no modifications. Fresh install of angular-cli. / ng new project / ng serve.

Comment: @LameCoder -- are you able to re-produce this exact error with a brand new project locally? If so, what OS are you using?

Comment: I got the output of the OS (ubuntu trusty), angular-cli, node, npm, and the "ng build" command and put them all here: https://gist.github.com/justinoverton/edcc294b95430f8ccfbb668e96e829f5

Comment: I am having the exact same issue
My app is brand new 
I used the angular cli to create the app
im on windows 10

Comment: @Lismore -- are you able/willing to make the project public for reproducibility?

Comment: sure, there is absolutely nothing in the project yet.  I just tried to push it to Github and something went wrong and wiped out my files locally.  Git showed the commit but crashed on the publish.  The commit never made it  I generated a new angular app via the cli and was able to reproduce the issue.  Here is the project https://github.com/lismore/biometric-advertising-app @JanNielsen

Comment: Awesome, @Lismore -- thanks! Cloned, unfortunately neither `ng serve`, `ng build`, nor `ng build --prod` generate the error for me on Linux. What do you do to generate the error?

Comment: all I do is "ng serve" - you get the error in the console and if you hit localhost:4200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to `html-webpack-plugin@2.28.0` or better.

This is a bug inadvertently introduce in `html-webpack-plugin@2.25.0`; see [HTML Webpack Plugin #555](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/pull/555/files) for details.